# Got error while installing Cordova/Ionic in Windows PC

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new in Mobile Development and I have just starting to learn Phonegap and Ionic to make Mobile Application.

But, while installing the Ionic Framework in my Windows 7 PC I am getting following errors:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v4.6.1
Xcode version: Not installed


******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************
```

Node and npm already installed on my machine.

Comment: When pasting errors from a console, please paste them as text rather than images. It will be good practice for you to repair this in your question, and that may discourage people from closing the question. Would you edit? Just paste and use the "code" formatting tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g cordova
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

try it.

Comment: @SandipMistry: when you say it didn't work, what did happen? Be as helpful and informative as you can when someone helps you. Do you have `npm` installed on the Windows command line?

Comment: @halfer Yes, npm is already installed. I got the same result while installing cordova.

Comment: @SandipMistry: got the same result as what?

Comment: what about path variables? I remember setting some path variables.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you installed node.js from nodejs.org and git files.....

1 step:
open cmd with "run as administrator"...then type npm install cordova(it will take some time to install)....
2 step:
now, npm install ionic

try it with a little bit patience...because to resolve this problem, it had took around 2 hours for me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with Ionic/Cordova. What worked for me was to opt into telemetry by running `cordova telemetry on`. I was able to run `cordova telemetry off` again afterwards, and the error was still gone.